# regex in python :groups and |

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I can't find how to proceed for a regular expression, here is an example:

```
string = "red\\/banana 36    monkey\\/apple 14   red\\/apple 23  red\\/horse 56  bull\\/red 67  monkey\\/red 45    bull\\/shark 89"
```

I want to do a **single regex** with re.match.group() which will take into account only the ones like red/xxxx and the ones like xxxx/red and group the xxxx **names only**, not couples:

I want to do:

```
print(match.group("beginningwithred") + " " + match.group("number")
```

and obtain:

```
banana 36
apple 23
horse 56
```

then do:

```
print(match.group("endingwithred") + " " + match.group("number")
```

and obtain:

```
bull 67
monkey 45
```

my current code goes like:

```
iterator = regex.finditer(string)
for match in iterator:
    regex = re.compile('red\\\\\\\\/(?P<beginningwithred>banana|apple|horse)|(?P<endingwithred>bull|monkey)\\\\\\\\/red (?P<number>\d\d)')
```

but it doesn't work, I can't use | between groups and python HOWTO doesn't help..
I tried with **{  }** too including the whole two expressions but it doesn't work either.
It must not be really complicated but I can't find out what's wrong.

Comment: Do you have to use regex for this, or would something simpler be acceptable?

Comment: actually its html code and I could parse it, but I need this to be very fast, therefore I prefer using regexes

Comment: Unrelated to the problem as such, but consider using raw strings (`r'string'`) to limit the number of escapes you have to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't completely follow, but it sounds like you want non-capturing groups around your alternatives:

```
(?:foo|bar|baz)
```

that lets you use `|` without creating a "real" group.

---

**update** why doesn't this help? is this not right?

```
>>> s="red\\/banana 36    monkey\\/apple 14   red\\/apple 23  red\\/horse 56  bull\\/red 67  monkey\\/red 45    bull\\/shark 89"
>>> r = re.compile(r'(?:red\\/(?P<begin>\w+)|(?P<end>\w+)\\/red)\s+(?P<number>\d+)')
>>> for m in r.finditer(s):
...     print(m.groups())

('banana', None, '36')
('apple', None, '23')
('horse', None, '56')
(None, 'bull', '67')
(None, 'monkey', '45')
```

---

**update2**

if you just want to print out the non-`None` values you can do something like:

```
  >>> for m in r.finditer(s):
  ...     print(','.join(g for g in m.groups() if g is not None))
```

Comment: with thoses, I will get a mix with things like red/red or monkey/monkey... if I use them, I will get the couples with the \\/ between names, which I dont want

Comment: i've extended my answer.  i think that is the kind of thing you are looking for.  if not, please explain more clearly why.

Comment: It helped and thank you both, btw andrew, there must be 2 \\ more to make it work. Like: r = re.compile(r'(?:red\\\\/(?P......

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's impossible to find an **extra_terrestial_regex** matching all the occurences, those with 'red' in first position and those with 'red' in second position, but being so that:

```
for mat in extra_terrestial_regex.finditer(s):
    print mat.group("beginningwithred") + " " + match.group("number")
```

will select only the matches with 'red' in first position and will skip the others.

.

It isn't a regex than can obtain such a result, it's only a function; do the following one perform what you want ?

```
import re

s = ('red\\/banana 36    monkey\\/apple 14  '
     'red\\/apple 23  red\\/horse 56  bull\\/red 67 '
     'monkey\\/red 45    bull\\/shark 89')


def gen(s,what,word):
    if what=='beginning':
        regx = re.compile(r'%s\\/([^ ]+) (\d+)' % word)
    elif what=='ending':
        regx = re.compile(r'([^ ]+)\\/%s (\d+)' % word)
    else:
        regx = re.compile('(\A).*(\Z)')
    for mat in regx.finditer(s):
        yield mat.groups()


print '\n'.join('%s %s' % x for x in gen(s,'beginning','red'))
print '----------------'
print '\n'.join('%s %s' % x for x in gen(s,'ending','red'))
print '----------------'
print '\n'.join('%s %s' % x for x in gen(s,'ZOU','red'))
print '----------------'
print '\n'.join('%s %s' % x for x in gen(s,'ending','apple'))
```

result

```
banana 36
apple 23
horse 56
----------------
bull 67
monkey 45
----------------

----------------
monkey 14
red 23
```